# How can i combine these lines?

Tags: c#, linq

My Linq query is

```
List<TopRated> TopRated = (from review in db.ProductReviews
                            group review by review.ProductID into product
                            select new TopRated
                            {
                              ProductName = product.Select(p => p.Products.Name).FirstOrDefault(),
                              Price = product.Select(p => p.Products.Price).FirstOrDefault(),
                              PriceOffer = product.Select(p => p.Products.PriceOffer).FirstOrDefault(),
                              ProductId = product.Key,
                              AverageRating = product.Average(p => p.Rating)
                            }).ToList();
```

can i combine these lines in one?

```
ProductName = product.Select(p => p.Products.Name).FirstOrDefault(),
Price = product.Select(p => p.Products.Price).FirstOrDefault(),
PriceOffer = product.Select(p => p.Products.PriceOffer).FirstOrDefault(),
```

I think that i "add overload" by doing something like the above.

Comment: No, not really, you can't. And there is nothing wrong with these lines being similar.

Comment: Can you show the definitions of your models? (e.g. ProductReview, Product..)

Comment: You can use String.Join() method to get a single string.  Maybe you really want to put results into a datatable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can utilize [let](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx) clause which uses a range variable. In my opinion it creates an intuitive and elegant syntax:

```
    var TopRated = (from review in db.ProductReviews
                    group review by review.ProductID into product
                    let firstProduct = product.FirstOrDefault()
                    select new 
                    {
                        ProductName = firstProduct.Products.Name,
                        Price = firstProduct.Products.Price,
                        PriceOffer = firstProduct.Products.PriceOffer,
                        ProductId = product.Key,
                        AverageRating = product.Average(p => p.Rating)
                    }).ToList();
```

For a deeper analysis you can use one of the IL decompilers to see how each of the proposed solutions compiles to IL. 
For performance analysis you can test using `StopWatch` class.

Comment: Beat me with a couple of minutes ;)

Comment: @GertArnold Yeah, such things happen now and then :)

Comment: Oh nice. I always forget about `let` because I tend to avoid query syntax; I prefer method syntax myself.  I'll give you one for that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, and in some cases it can greatly affect your query performance.

```
List<TopRated> TopRated = (from review in db.ProductReviews
                        group review by review.ProductID into product
                        select new 
                        {
                          FirstProduct=product.FirstOrDefault(p=>p.Products)
                          ProductId = product.Key,
                          AverageRating = product.Average(p => p.Rating)
                        }).Select(product=>new TopRated {
                          ProductName = product.FirstProduct.Name,
                          Price = product.FirstProduct.Price,
                          PriceOffer = product.FirstProduct.PriceOffer,
                          ProductId = product.ProductId,
                          AverageRating = product.AverageRating
                        }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
List<TopRated> TopRated = 
   (from review in db.ProductReviews
    group review by review.ProductID into product
    select new { ProductId = product.Key, Products = product.FirstOrDefault().Products, AverageRating = product.Average(p => p.Rating) } into topRated
    select new TopRated
        {
            ProductName = topRated.Products.Name,
            Price = topRated.Products.Price,
            PriceOffer = topRated.Products.PriceOffer,
            ProductId = product.Key,
            AverageRating = topRated.AverageRating
        })
   .ToList();
```

I would be curious to know what effect this has on the query performance as well as the differences between the query generated by your method and the query generated by this method.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but better first do the grouping and aggregates, and then get the product info via join like this:

```
var query = (from review in db.ProductReviews
             group review by review.ProductID into reviews
             select new { ProductId = reviews.Key, AverageRating = reviews.Average(item => item.Rating) } into summary
             join product in db.Products on summary.ProductId equals product.Id
             select new TopRated
             {
                 ProductName = product.Name,
                 Price = product.Price,
                 PriceOffer = product.PriceOffer,
                 ProductId = product.Id,
                 AverageRating = summary.AverageRating
             });
var sqlQuery = query.ToString();
var result = query.ToList();
```

or in this particular case (only one aggregate) even simpler:

```
var query = (from product in db.Products
             select new TopRated
             {
                 ProductName = product.Name,
                 Price = product.Price,
                 PriceOffer = product.PriceOffer,
                 ProductId = product.Id,
                 AverageRating = product.ProductReviews.Average(review => review.Rating)
             });
var sqlQuery = query.ToString();
var result = query.ToList();
```